# nl2br doesn't work with htmlspecialchars

Tags: php

So i'm trying to get my `nl2br` to work but it just wont work the way i hope it would.

As it retrieves text from a database, i want it to recognise the \n with the `nl2br`  I have `htmlspecialchars` which is the reason it doesn't work. How would i solve this issue?

My code:
The post variable looks like this

`$post = nl2br($row['p_post']);`

Which means that it ends up inside the `htmlspecialchars()`

`echo '<p>'.htmlspecialchars($post, ENT_QUOTES).'</p>;`

I tried to put it like this `echo '<p>'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($post, ENT_QUOTES)).'</p>;` but that ended up looking as if there was no `nl2br` at all.

How it looks from the start
[image: How it looks]

[image]

How it looks after i've added the nl2br

Comment: Do you see this in the webbrowser?

Comment: @AbraCadaver How would it not? Otherwise it wouldn't create the visible <br />

Comment: Your second version works for me, see http://ideone.com/YSd9VQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed, it seemed that another variable collided with it somehow so that it wouldn't actually make the `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You're double encoding the tags:

```
$foo = "how\ndoes\nthis\nlook";
$post = nl2br($foo); // $post is now "how<br>does<br>this<br>look"
$temp = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($post)); // $temp is now "how&lt;br&gt;does etc..."
echo '<p>how&lt;br&gt;does&lt; etc...';
```

You converted the line breaks to break tags, then you html encoded the break tags to html character entities, so your browser renders those tags as "visual" tags, and not HTML line breaks at all.